# Collibra workflow sending mails scripts

Tags: groovy, workflow, email-templates, collibra

I'm newbie to Collibra workflow and now I have to maintain old workflow script.
It's used this code:

```
mail.sendMails(userIds, "process", null, execution);
```

When running, error is: **Unable to find resource: 'email-templates/workflow-notifications/my_rule/process|en'**

I searched for help and found an example that have a email template inside folder **email-templates/workflow-notifications** . But I cannot find it in collibra UI or collibra console.
Please help me how to solve this problem by anyway. Ty ty ty .